# Как сверстать такой компонент шаринга?

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста, какая HTML структура вёрстки должна быть для такого компонента?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос в виде картинки бесполезен для базы знаний.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/dev/share/

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/156185/

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

div {
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  margin-right: 25px;
}

a {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Some text here</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-ads"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```